# PHP - unix timestamp from seconds to milliseconds

Tags: php

So I need to convert an unix timestamp which is in seconds to milliseconds.
This line seems to be not working

```
$unixtime = strtotime($timestamp_conv."+3 hour") * 1000;
```

I basically need a 13 digit timestamp. 
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: _"This line seems to be not working"_ - because?

Comment: What's the content of `$timestamp_conv` exactly?

Comment: You need to share more information. What is the value of `$timestamp_conv`, and what do you mean specifically by *This line seems to be not working*?

Comment: It's giving me some different 10 digit number. For example  `$timestamp_conv = 1492498242`

Comment: the code line looks good, I tried it with `$timestamp_conv = 'now';` and got a 13 digit float... you need to set `$timestamp_conv` as a string not a unix timestamp... see [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, `$timestamp_conv` already is a (second-)timestamp, you want to convert to a (milliseconds-)timestamp. You, however, also try to add some offset (3 hours) to it.

With simple arithmetics this would look like this

```
// add the three hours: 3 hours of 60 minutes of 60 seconds each
$timestamp_conv += 3 * 60 * 60;

// convert to milliseconds base
$unixtime = $timestamp_conv * 1000;
```

Comment: Hello
WHy does it need to add 3 hours?

Comment: @inrob that was part of OPs question to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime` from php, it's more intuitive.

```
<?php
$t = new \DateTime();
$t->setTimestamp(1492498242);
$t->modify("+3 hours");
echo $t->getTimestamp()*1000;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: HI, why 3 hours specifically?

Comment: @inrob that's the op request.